# Download Google Tag Manager container binary file with Google's API Client Library for Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth, google-tag-manager, google-api-java-client

I use the [TagManager API](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v1/) to retrieve/manipulate data in my Google Tag Manager configuration. The only problem I have now is that I can't download the binary file generated for each container version using that api (it is used by Android SDK). To be clear, I'm talking about the file which can be downloaded via:

```
https://tagmanager.google.com/api/accounts/[accountId]/containers/[container_id]/versions/[version_id]/download
```

The base URL of the TagManager API is different to the one above (`https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v1/`), so the [`GoogleCredential`](https://google.github.io/google-api-java-client/releases/1.21.0/javadoc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html) I've generated using my service account doesn't work for this download, as it is out of scope ([`TagManagerScopes`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/tagmanager/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/tagmanager/TagManagerScopes.html) to be specific).

I tried to find something in Google Developers Console to allow arbitrary url's like the one for the binary file, but I couldn't find anything. I might be approaching the OAuth part from a wrong angle altogether, this API is still very new to me.

Is it even possible to download this file programmatically? If yes, could you please explain how to achieve this?